# Non-existence of limit cycle of a polynomial system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, limit-cycles

I have been assigned a project in which I need to study the following system:
$$\begin{cases}\dot{x} = x(ax^n + by^n + c)\\\dot{y} = y(dx^n + ey^n + f)\end{cases}$$
where $(a,b,c,d,e,f) \in \mathbb{R}^6$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I'm being asked to find a relationship between the parameters of the system, $\phi(a,b,d,c,e,f,n)$ such that if $\phi(a,b,c,d,e,f,n) = 0$ the system may have periodic orbits but cannot contain limit cycles.

I've tried using Bendixson-Dulac 's Theorem in order to find a function $B$ and an open set $U$ homeomorphic to a crown (disc with a hole) around every critic point and, perhaps, move on from there knowing there might exist periodic orbits. However, I don't believe this is even close to a possible solution and don't really know how to move on.

Any hints on how I could be facing this problem are more than welcome.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hint.

Regarding the differential equation

$$
M(x,y) dx+N(x,y) dy = 0
$$

if $N_x = M_y$ then there exist $V(x,y)= C$ such that

$$
V_x dx + V_y dy = 0
$$

in our case if

$$
\cases{c+f=0\\ (n+1)e+b=0\\ (n+1)a+d=0}
$$

then

$$
V(x,y) = a x^n y + \frac bn x y^n+c x y
$$

is a solution. If $V(x,y)$ with $n$ even has relative minima/maxima then the associated differential system will have periodic orbits. Example

$$
V(x,y) = 3 x y+x^2 y-x y^2
$$

has a relative minimum at $x = -1, y = 1$. Attached the level curves around this point.

[image]

The associated differential system

$$
\cases{
\dot x = -x(3 + x - 2 y)\\
\dot y = y(3 + 2 x - y)
}
$$

with the near stream plot

[image]

NOTE

Limit cycles occur only in dissipative systems.