# Can someone help me with good oscillation pictures corresponding to stable and unstable limit cycles?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-dynamics, limit-cycles

I have seen a lot of pictures of stable and unstable limit cycles in 2D planes using [nullclines and trajectories](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/limit-cycle). I am trying to understand them using oscillations of a particle nearby. If you give me some ideas using pictures that you draw using programming or by hand that will be useful.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Like in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2914116/provide-a-full-phase-plane-analysis-for-the-model/2914753#2914753, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2772499/non-existence-of-limit-cycle-of-a-polynomial-system/3343348#3343348, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4675079/critical-points-of-an-autonomous-dynamical-systems-depending-on-a-parameter/4675086#4675086? Or are you more interested in stable orbits of a forced system like in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2679760/numerical-evaluation-of-the-period-of-a-limit-cycle/2988680#2988680?

Comment: What are "oscillations of a particle nearby"? How do you get a particle into a 2D vector field defining a dynamical system? What does "nearby" mean, do you mean solutions that have IC close to a periodic orbit? What are the oscillations, is that some kind of acoustics, or more general perturbation term?